# How to hide WPF Grid Overflow (like CSS overflow:hidden)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, grid, overflow

I'm currently creating a metro styled app. 
Because of this I need to extend my client area out of my window to draw the shadow. 
The problem now is that I have a button set to Margin="0,0,15,15" and of course it draws itself also in this shadow area. How can I hide this? In CSS I would just apply overflow:hidden to the "Content" or the UserControl.

[image: problem]

The basic WPF structure is like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Margin="15" Background="White">
    <Grid.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" BlurRadius="15" Direction="470"/>
    </Grid.Effect>
        <Grid x:Name="Content">
        <UserControl></UserControl> // This is where the arrow button is with Margin="0,0,15,15"
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Normally you can use some container and set its [`ClipToBounds`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.cliptobounds.aspx) to `true`.

Comment: I'm to some extent new to WPF, though familiar with it for over a year. I'm amazed each time when I discover some new feature. WPF awesome. God bless the one who came up with this idea!